# Is there an equivalent idiom for "Slow and steady wins the race"?

Tags: traducción, modismos

English has an idiom: "Slow and steady wins the race." It is used to describe situations where slow, steady progress towards a goal is better than a rushed attempt to achieve things all at once (and I believe it comes from the fable of [The Tortoise and the Hare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tortoise_and_the_Hare)). Is there an equivalent idiom in Spanish?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here goes a bunch:

"Vísteme despacio, que tengo prisa" (quote from [Ferdinand VII](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernando_VII_de_Espa%C3%B1a#Anecdotario))

Something like: *Dress me slowly, for I am in a hurry.*

---

"Las prisas son malas consejeras"

Something like: *Hurries are bad advisers*.

---

"Sin prisa pero sin pausa"

*Slowly but steadily*

---

"Quien va piano va lontano"

(this sounds pretty Italian-borrowed to me, but it means *Who goes slowly goes/gets far*)

---

"Poco a poco, hila la vieja el copo".

*Little by little the old lady spins the woll yarn* (related to spinning a yarn; more information in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_spinning))

---

Probably the closest one to the idiom you mention is this one (also based on the [Aesop fable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tortoise_and_the_Hare)):

"Conejo rapido no llega lejos. Tortuga llega segura."

*The fast rabbit doesn't reach far. The turtle arrives safe.* Although I must say that I have never heard this in Spain.

Comment: In Mexico is very common "Lento pero seguro" - "Slowly but surely".

Comment: That one is Italian, indeed. The original is *piano, piano si va lontano*. The one @SergioRomero mentions in his comment is also used in Spain, I've heard it quite a few times.

Comment: `Quien va piano va lontano` is Italian not Spanish. The majority of the others I have never heard them myself. `Lento pero seguro` is the best choice at least in Spain.

Comment: The one I heard was, "poco a poco se llega lejos".  That's almost like one of the ones you posted.

Comment: I think that "sin prisa pero sin pausa" is in fact said inversely: "sin pausa pero sin prisa", but with exactly the same meaning.

Answer (score 6):

`Lento pero seguro` conveys a very similar meaning to `Slow and steady wins the race.` because it is used to express that slowness is a good thing and gets you to your targets.

Example:

```
- estas tardando mucho, ¿no?
- yo voy lento pero seguro
```

That is widely accepted and recognized (at least in Spain).

Answer (score 1):

Another mexican one:

> Más vale paso que dure que trote que canse.

Loosely translated to

> A pace that lasts is better than a trot that tires.

Comment: Esta merece ser la respuesta aceptada, por lejos. Las otras son mucho más de manual y mucho menos creativas

Answer (score 0):

In **Chile** is very common the expression

> despacito por las piedras.

It is an evolution of the phrase

> Irse despacio por las piedras [go slowly through the stones]

but usually the verb is omitted and the diminutive "despacito" is used instead "despacio".

For example, this dialog:

> -Me gusta mucho esa mina. [I like that girl]
>
> -¡Qué bien! Pero despacito por las piedras... [Well, but take it slow]

Answer (score -1):

I've heard it as

> Despacio con calma gana la carrera. (Slow with calmness wins the race)